# Как заполнить пустые значение DataFrame по примеру?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Всем привет!

Есть следующий DataFrame:

| Название | ID | Дата |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Точка А | 1 | 01.11 |
| Точка А |  | 02.11 |
| Точка А | 2 | 02.11 |
| Точка B |  | 02.11 |
| Точка B | 3 | 01.11 |
| Точка B | 4 | 02.11 |

Нужно заполнить пропуски в столбце ID, но ID должен быть взят именно по последней дате у каждой точки, т.е. если смотреть на пример, то у точки А должен быть ID 2, а у точки B - 4. Вопрос, как можно это сделать с помощью pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df["ID"] = df["ID"].fillna(df.groupby("Название")["ID"].transform("last"))
```

результат:

```
In [273]: df
Out[273]:
  Название   ID  Дата
0  Точка А  1.0  1.11
1  Точка А  2.0  2.11
2  Точка А  2.0  2.11
3  Точка B  4.0  2.11
4  Точка B  3.0  1.11
5  Точка B  4.0  2.11
```